# Relation between $\mathrm{Proj}(A[tI])$ and $\mathrm{Proj}(A[tJ])$ for ideals $I$ and $J$ of $A$ with $I^2 \subset J \subset I$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, schemes

Let $k$ be a field and $A$ a noetherian local $k$-algebra. 
Let $I$ and $J$ be two ideals of $A$ with $I^2 \subset J \subset I$. 
Let $A[tI] = \bigoplus\limits_{i\geq 0} t^i I^i$ and $A[tJ] = \bigoplus\limits_{i\geq 0} t^i J^i$ be the Rees algebras for $I$ and $J$, respectively.

**Question:** Is it true that $\mathrm{Proj}(A[tI]) \cong \mathrm{Proj}(A[tJ])$ as $k$-schemes? 
If not, then in what condition one can get such an isomorphism of $k$-schemes?

Comment: It seems like this is almost never true without some strong hypothesis; blowing up $(x,y)$ and $(x,y^2)$ in $k[x,y]$ give very different results, as the latter is singular and the former not. One case where it is immediately seen to be true is if I and J are both powers of another ideal.

Comment: Thanks you for the example.